# 'except' in try statement (inside while loop) isn't working

Tags: python, while-loop, except

I've written a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the
user enters `"done"`. If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number.

The problem is the code never gets to the `except` part of the code (user should get an error for not entering anything or for entering invalid characters (anything not `'done'` or a number).
What am I doing wrong?

```
numbers=(input("Enter a number or 'done' to quit: "))
count=1
total_num=int(numbers)
while True:
    numbers=(input("Enter another number or 'done' to quit: "))
    try:
        if (numbers.isalpha() and numbers=='done'):  #elif numbers.isalpha() and numbers=='done':
            break
        elif numbers.isdigit():
            numbers=int(numbers)
            total_num+=int(numbers)
            count+=1
    except:
        print('Valid a number or done to quit:' )

print('sum is', total_num)
print('count is', count)
print('average is', int(total_num/count))
```

Comment: try-except is for handling exceptions. In this case it seems like if-elif-else would suffice

Comment: What input should trigger the `except`? It looks like the testd already cover the different possibilities to avoid exceptions.

Comment: Could just be an error in indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood the point of the `try..except` block. You don't need to check if the input `isdigit`, since that precludes any errors from being thrown. Just try to convert the input to `int`, and if this fails, you'll fall through to the `except`. There, you can check if the input is `== "done"`, and break out:

```
while True:
    numbers = input("Enter another number or 'done' to quit: ")
    try:
        numbers = int(numbers)
        total_num += numbers
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        if numbers == "done": break
        print('Valid a number or done to quit:' )
```

Note that I qualified the `except` clause to only catch `ValueError`s, since it is a bad practice to catch all errors -- that can hide actual problems with your code, and disable the ability to interrupt the program with `Ctrl+C`

Comment: Thank you so much! I struggled for days on that (embarrassingly)!

Comment: @Blckknght You're right of course thanks. The difference is for negative numbers `int('-2')` vs. `'-2'.isdigit()`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that apparently breaks the code so the Except statement is never executed.

You can put an else statement with same thing as Except:

```
numbers=(input("Enter a number or 'done' to quit: "))
count=1
total_num=int(numbers)

while True:
    numbers=(input("Enter another number or 'done' to quit: "))
    try:
        if (numbers.isalpha() and numbers=='done'):  #elif numbers.isalpha() and numbers=='done':
            break
        elif numbers.isdigit():
            numbers=int(numbers)
            total_num+=int(numbers)
            count+=1
        else:
            print('Valid a number or done to quit:' )
    except:
        print('Valid a number or done to quit:' )

print('sum is', total_num)
print('count is', count)
print('average is', int(total_num/count))
```

Unless you find some input that breaks your code I suggest removing it and stay only with the if elif else